# svg keep element size when adding text

Tags: css, svg

I'm quite new and trying to combine some drawing with texts or draw more. I draw a circle with sections, I want the text to display on center of each. But my viewport doesn't have enough space for text because I draw circle first, when I increase svg width & height my circle becomes bigger which I don't want it happens. I need space to draw lines and texts. Please suggest me how can I keep the circle size (300,300) and have space. Thanks

```
   <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <g transform="translate(150,150)" fill="none" stroke-width="45">
      <path stroke="#CBA135" d="M-110 0 A110 110 0 0 10-110"/> 
      <path stroke="#7EC34F" d="M0 -110 A110 110 0 0 1110 0"/>  
      <path stroke="#ABDB92" d="M110 0 A110 110 0 0 1-110 0"/>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(150,150)" fill="none" stroke-width="2">
        <path stroke="#fff" d="M0 -137 L0,-82"/>
        <path stroke="#fff" d="M-137 0 L-82,0"/>
        <path stroke="#fff" d="M137 0 L82,0"/>
        <path stroke="#333" d="M117 -99 L137,-119"/>
        <path stroke="#333" d="M0 147 L0,167"/>
         <path stroke="#333" d="M-117 -99 L-137,-119"/>
        <text x="-169" y="-140" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="18px" 
        fill="#438736">WORD1 WORD2</text>
```

[Here's link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/ducfelix/pen/LLewyK)

Answer (score 0):

> When I increase svg width & height my circle becomes bigger which I don't want

The viewBox attribute allows you to specify that a given set of graphics stretch to fit a particular container element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

I would suggest to remove your ViewBox element and just set the height and width on your SVG. As much as you need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about making circles or anything, but maybe it would work if you make the circle `position: relative`  and the text field `position: absolute`

Comment: The `position` property is not valid for SVG elements.